# How do I install Sigil in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: repository, qt5, epub

Is there a ppa I can use to install Sigil in Ubuntu 15.04?

The old `ppa:rgibert/ebook` doesn't work for me any more.

Comment: per rafal's answer it's standard in apt.  works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 16.04, **Sigil is available in the official repositories.**

---

There were some repositories that maintained Sigil for Ubuntu 15.04:

**i2p**: https://launchpad.net/~i2p.packages/+archive/ubuntu/i2p

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:i2p.packages/i2p
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sigil
```

**mapreri**: https://launchpad.net/~mapreri/+archive/ubuntu/sigil

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapreri/sigil
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sigil
```

Though it is important to note that i2p.packages repository *doesn't contain only Sigil*, and updating after adding it may upgrade other packages.

Answer (score 4):

#### Ubuntu 16.04 (and later)

Sigil is in official repositories for Ubuntu 16.04, so you can install it without adding any 3rd party PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install sigil
```

Answer (score 2):

**The latest version Sigil 0.8.2 is available only here at the moment:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:i2p.packages/i2p
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sigil
```

Comment: Been fighting with this all day, and this was the only thing that managed to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW,

**Additional**, you need the more up to date `qt5` libraries, Found in  `ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunab/sigil-git
```

Otherwise installing Sigil will fail due to older `qt5` in the standard repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You'll rarely find last version of Sigil in any ppa (0.7.2 there, 0.7.4 the last one).

The sunab/sigil-git ppa states it is for testing only; it uses "the latest git snapshot from git master branch of Sigil a WYSIWYG epub editor".

You can try the deb (now updated to 0.7.4) shared, with instructions, at mobileforums:

http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=211754

Answer (score 0):

The [xiota PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=sigil%20xiota) has also been keeping up to date on sigil.

Answer (score 0):

This might go against the grain for a few people, but the Windows version works fine in WINE...

[Windows Version Here](https://code.google.com/p/sigil/downloads/detail?name=Sigil-0.7.4-Windows-Setup.exe)