# Installing Sigil on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I found this post: 
[How do I install Sigil?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297286/installing-sigil-on-ubuntu-13-04),
but it doesn't work for Ubuntu 13.10. There is no package for saucy.

Is there a way to install Sigil for 13.10 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Sigil on Ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/297286/installing-sigil-on-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: @JorgeCastro Why is this a duplicate?

Comment: @Seth the PPA is up to date now, they're the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

The ppa was was apparently not ready at the time of my upgrade.
So installing Sigil is exactly as for 13.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunab/sigil-git
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install sigil
```